# Issues with AP9101C Lipo protection IC and the auto-wakeup feature

Tags: protection, lipo, bms

I'm developing a pcb for a product powered by a single-cell li-ion battery. Since I couldn't find an appropriate battery with a built in protection ic, I decided to add one to my design. After searching for a chip that could handle slightly higher currents (~5A) and that would be available in higher quantities I finally stumbled upon the AP9101C family made by Diodes Incorporated. I basically copy-pasted the typical application circuit from the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.pl/datasheet/2/115/DIOD_S_A0007229744_1-2542938.pdf) and just selected the variant of the chip (AP9101CAK6-AYTRG1) with voltage thresholds appropriate for the battery that I have.
At first I didn't realise there are also two vastly different variants of the chip. The first one has a "Power-Down Mode" while the other has an "Auto-wakeup function". These two modes specify the behaviour upon connecting the battery to the circuit for the first time. According to the datasheet: "For power-down mode, when first connecting AP9101C system board to the battery, it is necessary to use charger or to short P- to the battery negative polarity". Unfortunately, connecting the charger does not result in the device waking-up. Only shorting the battery's negative terminal to the board's ground activates the ic. I also tried using the variant with auto-wakeup, which to my understanding, should wakeup automatically whenever the voltage of the li-ion is greater than the overdischarge release voltage. This however is not the case. I also need to kick start the ic by shorting the two terminals. So both versions of the chip function basically the same. Although that's not an issue during the manufacturing process, I just received a note from one of our beta testers stating that his device just died and will not turn on. This has never happened to me so far but I can assume that his protection circuit probably entered the powered-down mode and it will not auto release, even after connecting the charger. Am I missing some obvious fact from the datasheet? I've read it multiple times already and I still cannot understand why the auto-wakeup variant does not auto wake.

I know how to design basic pcbs but I've never considered myself an electronics engineer and I only design circuits in between various software development projects so I imagine I probably skipped some important details. Any help would be welcome.
Maybe someone has some experience with this particular chip or at least could propose a more common, and well documented alternative for it?

Here's the exact schematic of my circuit. My charger is connected to +BATT and GND.
The two mosfets with their Rdson of 16mOhms give me discharge overcurrent protection set to  4.7A and charge overcurrent of 3.1A. Apart from the issue with waking up the circuit functions properly.

[image: schematic2]

#### EDIT

I recently got back to trying to fix this issue. I found a different protection IC that matched the pinout and had similar parameters and I tested it as well. It behaved in exactly the same manner so I started to check everything thoroughly and I think I finally found what's causing the issue. An overcurrent event is monitored by checking the VM voltage. When it exceeds 100mV the discharge mosfet is turned off. However, when that happens, VM is also pulled high internally, which pulls up my GND line of the entire circuit to +BATT. And to exit the overcurrent state VM needs to go back down to less than <100mV, which cannot happen because the GND is now 'floating'.
Does anyone have an idea how I could force the VM pin back to 0V?
How do similar ICs work when they're soldered directly to the battery and put in a case, or just covered over with kapton tape? I imagine you don't just throw the battery away.

Connecting the charger is one way of waking the IC up, but only assuming the battery is not fully charged yet. When it's full the charger does not activate and well, the circuits GND is still shifted by VCC in regard to the battery's negative terminal.

So to sum it up. Is there an easy way to make sure the VM voltage returns to 0V automatically after an overcurrent event?

Comment: What is your charging voltage at no current?

Comment: At the end of the charging cycle it's around 4.2V. But some current is still flowing. When the charger shuts down, well it's just 0V. I updated the description above because I think I know what's happening.